# JavaScript regex split consecutive string (vs Java)

Tags: javascript, java, regex, split, regex-lookarounds

I have this splitting regex to group consecutive words in String

`/(?<=(.))(?!\1)/g`

So in Java the above regex would split the string as I'm **expected** like this

```
"aaabbbccccdd".split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)");
// return [aaa, bbb, cccc, dd]
```

but in JS the same regex will split like this, included my capture group 1

```
'aaabbbccccdd'.split(/(?<=(.))(?!\1)/g);
/// return ['aaa', 'a', 'bbb', 'b', 'cccc', 'c', 'dd']
```

So is there anyway to avoid capture group in result in JS (I've tried *(?:...)* but then I can't use *\1* anymore)

And if you have other way or improvement to split consecutive words in JS (using or not using regex), please share it, thank you.

Comment: I would recommend not expecting JavaScript to be like Java.

Comment: Well, I'm already aware of the differences in behavior of the 2 languages. But what I'm not expecting is just the split API of JS, does not work as I though a splitting API would work

Comment: Do you just want `'aaabbbccccdd'.match(/(.)\1*/g);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep your current logic but just filter off the even index list elements:

```js
var input = "aaabbbccccdd";
var matches = input.split(/(?<=(.))(?!\1)/)
                   .filter(function(d, i) { return (i+1) % 2 != 0; });
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: I guess that's one way to filter out the unwanted group, really weird that JS string split behaves like this, kind of inconvenience

Comment: It is a limitation of the API for this particular problem.  There are other cases where you want to retain the split delmiter.  In that case, having the ability to retain it by making it a capture group comes in handy.